# Sort File Creationtime in gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, file-io

i have a gridview that retrieve a list of name and file creationdatetime from servermappath  and try to sort by creationtime by this

```
    Function GetTable() As DataTable

        Dim filePaths() As String = getFiles(Server.MapPath("~/path/"), "*" + Session("Uauthen") + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim tb As New DataTable()
        tb.Columns.Add("FileName")
        tb.Columns.Add("FileCreationTime")
        Dim dv As New DataView(tb)
  dv.Sort = "FileCreationTime DESC"
        Dim sortedDT As DataTable = dv.ToTable()

        'Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths

            sortedDT.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath), File.GetCreationTime(filePath).ToString("d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"))


        Next

        Return sortedDT

    End Function
```

but nothing happened on gridview that still not sort there is another way to sort them ?

Comment: attach sample code how you get `filePaths`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define variable type in column

```
tb.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(String))
tb.Columns.Add("FileCreationTime",typeof(DateTime))
```

DataTable DateTime Column Sort:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1267353/2393006.aspx

Comment: Thank you Yu Yenkan :) , now I had  solved my problem by re-arrange sequence and it's work

Comment: @TouchyVivace: please mark as answer the post that helped you